# Render Depth to texture & samplerCubeShadow WebGL 2.0

Tags: webgl, render-to-texture, webgl2

I am trying to adapt an OpenGL shadow mapping code uing samplerCubeShadow to WebGL, and i desperately systematically fall into a cul-de-sac since valid data format and storage are clearly not the same between the first and the second.

I know I can achieve shadow mapping using other sampler than `sampler*Shadow` and by rendering into texture in some other way, but, i want, if possible achieve the same way as i did in OpenGL.

My problem is to found (if it exist !) the good combination of format, internal format, and what WebGL/GLSL expect for the samplerCubeShadow sampler...

### 1. question: the destination depth texture format.

In OpenGL I use the following format as depth texture:

`GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT`

But is seems the only accepted combination for WebGL for `DEPTH_ATTACHEMENT` is

`gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT`

I tryed `gl.FLOAT` and `gl.HALF_FLOAT` but the the `texImage2D` refuse another type than `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

Is it the good format for depth texture in WebGL ? If yes, so, WebGL stores depth data in a 16 bits integer instead of a float, this sounds strange, but not a real problem since 16 bits is 16 bits. Is it really the only acceptable format for depth texture in WebGL ?

### 2. the problem: the texture is not renderable

I can draw in this texture without error, however, when comes the moment to bind the texture into my `samplerCubeShadow`, WebGL throws me an error i never seen in my life:

`texture bound to texture unit # is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.`

### From this point

Either I found a "renderable" format but this cannot be used as `DEPTH_ATTACHEMENT`, or I found a suitable format for `DEPTH_ATTACHEMENT`, which is not "renderable"... So, what is the solution ?

### Pseudo code:

```
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, shadow_cube);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0x2800, gl.LINEAR);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0x2800, gl.LINEAR);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_R, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, gl.COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, gl.GREATER);
 for(var c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+c, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 512, 512, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);
 }
```

---

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, offscreen_fbo);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, null, 0);
for(var c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
   gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+c, shadow_cube, 0);
   // draw things...
}
```

---

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE#);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, shadow_cube);
```

---

Edit: In the OpenGL code, the destination depth texture have an extra parameter:

`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_LUMINANCE);`

However, the `DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE` does not exists in WebGL... maybe this is what is missing for this to work in WebGL ?

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found the solution... There was at least one error.

### 1. use texStorage2D instead of texImage2D with null

While a call to `texImage2D` with `NULL` data works with OpenGL, it seem WebGL prefer a call to `texStorage2D` with `gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16`

Il replaced this:

```
for(var c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+c, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 512, 512, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);
 }
```

by this:

```
gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 1, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, this._smap_res, this._smap_res);
```

### 2. The COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE enum is not valid in WebGL

Currently the good enum for WebGL is actually COMPARE_**REF**_TO_TEXTURE, the enum GL_COMPARE_**R**_TO_TEXTURE is OpenGL specific. This is tricky because WebGL does not thow error if you pass the `gl.COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE` enum !

So, I changed:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, gl.COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);
```

To:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, gl.COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
```

An now, all work fine !

Comment: the fact that `texStorage2D` worked at `texImage2D` did not just means the code was doing something else wrong. Anything that can be done with `texStorage2D` can also be done with `texImage2D`. For `texParameteri` the reason it didn't generate an error is because `COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE` is `undefined`. For numbers `undefined` gets coerced to 0 which is the same as `NONE` which is a valid value for `TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE`

Comment: I agree that in theory, the `texStorage2D` is a kind of alias for `texImage2D` with NULL, but in this case, the `texImage2D` with `gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT` combo does not work while  `texStorage2D` only a require a `gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16` format as argument, so WebGL makes its internal cook with this... The issue with `texImage2D` is probably a matter of format combo, but which combo is the good one ? This remain a mistery for me...